# How to get list of events performed by user using Mixpanel API

Tags: api, events, endpoint, mixpanel, moengage

I need an API that Gets all the events performed by user. We are using Mixpanel engage API endpoint to get user's device specific data. But can't seem to find any API that gets events performed by user by userID or mobile number.If anyone know such API provided by mixpanel would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

I tried the following endpoints provided in these [docs](https://developer.mixpanel.com/reference/overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I found the solution by using mixpanel's https://developer.mixpanel.com/reference/activity-stream-query
Api end point. Incase if anyone looking for answer.

Answer (score -2):

(function(c,a){if(!a.__SV){var b=window;try{var d,m,j,k=b.location,f=k.hash;d=function(a,b){return(m=a.match(RegExp(b+"=([^&]*)")))?m[1]:null};f&&d(f,"state")&&(j=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(d(f,"state"))),"mpeditor"===j.action&&(b.sessionStorage.setItem("_mpcehash",f),history.replaceState(j.desiredHash||"",c.title,k.pathname+k.search)))}catch(n){}var l,h;window.mixpanel=a;a._i=[];a.init=function(b,d,g){function c(b,i){var a=i.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],i=a[1]);b[i]=function(){b.push([i].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var e=a;"undefined"!==typeof g?e=a[g]=[]:g="mixpanel";e.people=e.people||[];e.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==g&&(a+="."+g);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};e.people.toString=function(){return e.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};l="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split(" ");for(h=0;hmixpanel.init("projecttoken");